# Algebric Simplifying Process

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

I was just viewing a tutorial on how to solve the integral of $\int{x\ \times\ 6 \div\sqrt{x}}\ dx$

And I noticed they simplified it to : $\int6\sqrt{x}\ dx$  , before they started on the integral.

I wanted to know how they did such a simplification process.

Comment: Write the root as an exponent of one half and use properties of exponents.

Comment: MathJax tip:  You don't have to `\space`.  All you need is `\ ` with an actual space following and it turns into a space automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x \times 6  \div \sqrt x = \frac{6x}{\sqrt x} = \frac{6\sqrt x \cdot \sqrt x}{\sqrt x} = 6\sqrt x$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Would it be possible to do the integral without simplifying it into 6(sqrt(x))?

Comment: @user36278 Sure, you could've used integration by parts for example.  Which is why we use algebraic simplification first

Comment: @ Simple Art Wow, I just tried to do it with integration by parts and the answer looks really complicated, and I think I might have done it incorrectly as the graphs don't match.

Comment: @user36278 $$\underset{\color{red}{u \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ dv}} {\int 6x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx } + \underset{\color{red}{v \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  du}} {\int 2\sqrt x \cdot6 dx } = \underset{\color{red}{u \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ v}} {6x\cdot 2\sqrt x }$$